# If we are using annotation based hibernate then do we require hbm.xml?

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate.I saw in my project we are using annotation for hibernate and we have not defined mapping class anywhere.In this project we are using spring also.so my question is If we are using annotation based hibernate then do we require hbm.xml?

Comment: No, you don't need it. Read the spring documentation to understand how Spring can define  hibernate session factory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're referring to Hibernate XML mapping files, they're definitely not required if you're using Hibernate Annotations.

Hibernate Annotations is an alternative to Hibernate XML Mapping files. They've got the same goal, which is among other things to define how an Entity maps to database columns, and how it relates to other Entities.

Actually you'd need to decide for a model or the other (Annotations or XML mappings). It is also possible to use an hybrid model, where some Entities are mapped with Annotations and some are mapped with XML mapping files. As explained for instance in [Is it possible to use both annotations and hbm.xml files in the same project in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8311622/851811)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to map your entities(Objects) with relations(Tables). use of Xml files are now obsolete but i would say if you are using Xml files then you can have clean entities with no annotation at all so you can migrate to any other ORM framework and use these entities. refer here to learn http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic.html#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic-mapping

You can also use annotation to map the entities thus it will require less code.Refer here to learn http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-entity

finally **no hbm.xml file required if you are using annotation for map your entities.**

Comment: XML mappings are *not* obsolete at all. They're still fully supported and [some still do use them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1862666/851811). Each one has its [pros and cons](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10191534/851811). IIRC there are a couple of very specific features that can be achieved only with XML mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, **Hibernate** relies on external XML files for its configuration: database mappings are defined in a set of XML mapping files and loaded at startup time.

There are many ways to create these mappings, either automatically, from an existing database schema or Java class model, or by hand.

In any case, you can end up with a considerable number of Hibernate mapping files.

Alternatively, you can use javadoc-style annotations, though this adds an extra step in your build process.

`And You also do not require hbm.xml files if you are using annotations.`

[Here](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2007/02/08/an-introduction-to-hibernate-3-annotations.html) is the quick reference for all you need to know about **mappings** for **hibernate**